# What is the issue with 10 digit mobile no data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I made a table for storing contact record of user of my website. It also contains a 10 digit mobile no.

Table structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE contact_user
(
id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
contact INT(10)
)
```

Now the problem is that if I insert a 10 mobile no.(e.g.9595891256) using phpmyadmin into contact field it will insert some random value and shows a warning saying "data out of column range"

But if I insert a simple 10 digit no (e.g.4561327894) then it works well and no warning is shown.

SO please tell me what is the issue in inserting a mobile no in this column?

I am using mysql 5.1 on ubuntu 11.04 and also using phpmyadmin.

Comment: +1, not so trivial as it seems.

Comment: @Johan thanks for +1 and understanding my mistake

Answer (score 7, accepted):

INT(10) does not mean a 10-digit number, it means an integer with a display width of 10 digits. Whether you put INT(2) or INT(10), MySQL still only stores an (unsigned, in this case) INT which has a maximum value of 4294967295.

You can use a BIGINT instead of INT to store it as a numeric. I wouldn't recommend this, however, because it won't allow for international numbers. If you are certain your application will only use US numbers, using BIGINT will save you 3 bytes per row over VARCHAR(10) -- if that sort of thing concerns you.

Since it is a phone number (and therefore you won't be doing numeric calculations against it), try using a VARCHAR(20). This allows you the ability to store international phone numbers properly, should that need arise.

Comment: it's my mistake that i forgot that something also going behind the INT(10) programatically.I am just taking it as a width :D :D

Comment: It's a common misconception, likely stemming from the fact that you also use `()` to specify size of `CHAR` and maximum size of `VARCHAR`. When the same symbols have different meanings, it's easy to misunderstand the behavior.

Comment: can you plz suggest me any good book or tutorial which contains information about  these general misconceptions.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum value for an INT in MySQL is 2147483647 (or 4294967295 if unsigned), according to the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html). If your value exceeds this limit, you integer will overflow, hence the not-that-random value.

Also, INT is not the best solution to store phone numbers. You might lose leading zeros if they are one or more. Also, international phone numbers start with a `+` sign. Consider using a VARCHAR. This will end up using more space in the database, but will provide more consistency.

Comment: you are also perfectly correct but i am sorry i can't mark more than one answer as correct but anyways thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

It is because of the max size of type INT you need to use a different type to hold a number that large. Try using BIGINT.